# dotenv multiple files for the same environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I am trying to use multiple config files for the same environment. So far, I was doing this for one configuration file:

```
node -r dotenv/config index.js dotenv_config_path=/etc/secrets/env.txt
```

But, now I have a requirement where I have to read from multiple configuration files for the same environment.

To achieve this, I tried this command. It loads the configurations from the first file only.

```
node -r dotenv/config index.js dotenv_config_path=/etc/secrets/env1.txt /etc/secrets/env2.txt
```

Is it possible to implement this? TIA.

Comment: Write a custom pre-required script that does what you want?

Comment: Do you mean, write a script that will read the config files and export those variables as environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The following answer does not work with preloading...**

*...but via directly using the dotenv module:*

---

> You can call dotenv twice or however many times you like to set variables from multiple files.
>
> ```
> const dotenv = require('dotenv')
> dotenv.config({ path: 'prod.env' })
> dotenv.config({ path: 'prod.secret.env' })
> ```

[Source](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/256#issuecomment-359116714)

**Remember to use**

```
dotenv.config({
 override: true,
})
```

In case you want to override env variables